# how does one divide stress in such a bridge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics

I want to build a spaghetti bridge like this:

[image: spaghetti]

I have two spaghetti types: T-type (designed to tolerate tension) and C-type (designed to tolerate compression).

A mass $m$ is hanging from the point shown in the picture.

How can I calculate the tension of the spaghetties to know whether the bridge will break or not?

Angles are 36° (180°/5).

I have written the forces for the joints. Assume that the joints and spaghetties are massless.

I haven't written any forces for the two side joints because they are support points and thus connected to fixed object so all the forces on them cancel.

The spaghetties which are being stretched are T-type and the other ones are C-type.

I know the tension of T spaghetties makes C-types' compression. But I have trouble **calculating**. Help me.

My own approach was:

At the hanging point we have 4 tensions and each are:

$$\vec{T_1}=T_1\cos36\hat i+T_1\sin36\hat j$$
$$\vec{T_2}=T_2\cos72\hat i+T_2\sin72\hat j$$
$$\vec{T_3}=-T_3\cos72\hat i+T_3\sin72\hat j$$
$$\vec{T_4}=-T_4\cos36\hat i+T_4\sin36\hat j$$

Also a gravity force:

$$\vec{F_g}=-mg\hat j$$

The sum of all of them is zero because the point doesn't move. so:

$$(T_1\cos36 +T_2\cos72 -T_3\cos72 -T_4\cos36)\hat i + (T_1\sin36 +T_2\sin72 +T_3\sin72 +T_4\sin36 -mg)\hat j=0$$

Thus:

$$T_1\cos36 +T_2\cos72 -T_3\cos72 -T_4\cos36 =0$$
$$T_1\sin36 +T_2\sin72 +T_3\sin72 +T_4\sin36 =mg$$

At this point I'm stuck.

Can anyone please provide me some hint so that I can proceed? I'm not wanting for any solution or *do-this-for-me* request; just a bit hint.

Comment: The easy way is to draw it in [Force Effect](https://forceeffect.autodesk.com/frontend/fe.html) and let it do the calculations

Comment: Hi BlueSky. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: The rigidity of spaghetti as a building material makes it pretty much impossible to do this calculation. Tension appears when a solid is deformed - but for a small displacement of the load point you will get a different amount of deformation of the different spaghettis. This is true even if the compressive elements can be ignored (they will buckle, eventually). Formulate your question in terms of "how does one divide stress when..." rather than "what is the stress in my bridge". That's the point of the (poorly named) "homework" policy. Good questions get good answers.

Comment: What you need to do is establish the force balance equations at each node.

Comment: You now have two equations with apparently four unknowns - but from symmetry you know that $T_1=T_4$ and $T_2=T_3$. That leaves you with just two equations and you can solve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) The easy way is to use a computer simulation program such as [Force Effect](https://forceeffect.autodesk.com/frontend/fe.html) (free)

[image: p1]
[image: p2]

b) The more appropriate way is to draw free body diagrams and calculate the tensions from the equilibrium equations

[image: fbd]

Equilibrium on the support *B*

$$ \left. \begin{aligned} 2 A_y & = m g \\ A_x & = C \cos 72° \\ A_y & = C \sin 72° \end{aligned} 
\right\} \begin{aligned} A_y &= 0.5 m g \\ A_x &= 0.162 m g \\ C & = 0.5257 m g \end{aligned}$$

Equilibrium on the node *D*

$$ \left. \begin{aligned} C \cos 72° + T \cos 36° - C \cos 36° & =0
\\ C \sin 72° - T \sin 36° - C \sin 36° & = 0 \end{aligned} \right\} \begin{aligned}
T & = 0.618 C = 0.325 m g \end{aligned} $$

Comment: Why $2A_y=mg$? in the B support point?

Comment: $2 A_y = m g$ comes from the overall structure (with assumed symmetry). I put it with the first equations for brevity. It is not a results of the balance at _B_. Also fixed an angle in the second set of equations.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the right and left corner are used to support the bridge. By assuming that the bridge is in static equilibrium you can find the external forces at the support points. Namely the sum of all external forces should add up to zero. Similar for the torque around each point. This should be enough to find the external forces at the supports, which then can used to find the tension/compression in each spaghetti stick, by using that the sum of all forces in each node should add up to zero.